# 4 normals can be drawn from any point to an ellipse proof doubt: How do we know the key quartic has 4 distinct real roots?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

**Theorem:** 4 normals can be drawn from any point to the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. $( a > b > 0)$

I had a doubt in the proof of the above statement given in my book.

**Proof given in Book.**
The normal at the point with eccentric angle $\phi$ is $ax\sec\phi - by \csc\phi = a^2 - b^2 $. Let P$(h,k)$ be any point in $\mathbb{R^2}$. If the normal passes through P: 
$$ah\sec\phi - bk \csc\phi = a^2 - b^2  = a^2e^2 $$
Let $ t = \tan \frac{\phi}{2}$, then $\cos \phi = \frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2}$ and $\sin \phi = \frac{2t}{1 + t^2}$. Substituting and rearranging, gives:

> $$bkt^4 + 2t^3(ah + a^2e^2) + 2t(ah - a^2e^2) - bk = 0 $$

This is a quartic in $t$, hence has 4 roots, corresponding to 4 points on the ellipse which are conormal.

> **Doubt:** My question is how do we know that the roots of that quartic equation are real and distinct? Because if not, then the theorem is not yet proved. I looked up the discriminant of a quartic on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function), but the inequalities are too difficult to handle. How can I show that the roots are all real and distinct?

Comment: What happens if your ellipse is a circle?

Comment: If it's a circle, then $a = b, e = 0$. Then two cases arise:
$(h,k) = (0,0)$: Then the polynomial vanishes to zero, and is true for all $\phi$.
$(h,k) \neq (0,0)$: The quartic becomes: $kt^4 + 2ht^3 + 2ht - k = 0 $. I don't know how to examine the nature of roots of this quartic too.

Comment: Actually it's possible to factorize the quartic for the special case of a circle: $kt^4+2ht^3+2ht−k=  (t^2 + 1) ( k t^2 + 2ht - k) = 0$. This always has 2 distinct real roots.

Comment: In the Wikipedia's notation for $P$, $D$, $\Delta$, we can write $$P = -12 a^2 (a e^2 + h)^2$$ $$D = -16 \left(
\;2 a^4 (a e^2 + h)^4 + (a^4 e^4 + 2 a^3 e^2 h + a^2 h^2 - 
      2 b^2 k^2)^2 + 8 a^2 b^2 h k^2 (a e^2 + h)
\;\right)$$ $$\Delta = 256 \left(\;(a^4 e^4 - a^2 h^2 - b^2 k^2)^3 - 27 a^6 b^2 e^4 h^2 k^2\;
\right)$$ Thus, $P$ and $D$ are certainly negative. So, "all you need to do" is show that $\Delta$ is positive.

Comment: Is this claim actually true? I have a hard time believing it for a point on the major axis but outside of the ellipse, for instance.

Comment: One premise of the theorem is that a > b > 0, so the theorem expressly excludes the case of a circle.

Comment: @Ashish - will a drawing help you? Actually you have up to 4 and at least 2. For a circle - the center has infinity.

Comment: @user7530 It's a theorem from The Elements of Coordinate Geometry by S L Loney. It's a quite standard text, so I'm assuming the theorem given would be true.

Comment: @Steve B The theorem does exclude the case of a circle, but if you plug $a = b$ in the equation of a normal, parametric form etc, and pretty much follow the same proof, it still holds. Moti: I'm not sure, maybe.

Comment: @Blue $D = P = 0$ iff $ (h,k) = (-ae^2,0)$; but $k \neq 0$ - as the case $k = 0$ yields a cubic in $t$, so that must be considered separately. $D \neq 0, P = 0$ iff $h =  -ae^2, k \neq 0$. For all other values of $(h,k)$, $D < 0, P < 0$ . And solving for $\Delta$ is exceedingly difficult.

Comment: This theorem - as stated - is false, see here: https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath505/kmath505.htm. Are you sure you wrote the exact statement?

Comment: Perhaps $P$ is meant to be interior to the ellipse.

Comment: @Ashish: Good point. I was making an unstated assumption —allowed by symmetry— that $(h,k)$ is in the closed First Quadrant, $h\geq 0$, $k\geq 0$. (Of course, an ideal analysis wouldn't rely on this, but it's a place to start.)

Comment: @Aretino Yes they have even proceeded to take the eccentric angles corresponding to the roots as  $\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3$ and $\phi_4$ and have shown that $\phi_1 + \phi_2 + \phi_3 + \phi_4 = (2n+1)\pi $. The theorem (as hinted by user7530 in his answer) seems false. However still is it possible to find the number of normals from P, for different points on the plane.

Comment: @Ashish As conclusion the theorem is right since you can draw such cases.

Comment: @Ashish see my drawing for the case of a point outside the Ellipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the theorem is simply false. Here is a rendering of the set of lines normal to an ellipse $(a=1, b=1/2)$:

[image]

There is a region (if I had to guess, bounded by the evolute of the ellipse: it would be interesting to prove this) where every point is indeed intersected by four normals to the ellipse. Outside this region, only two normals can be drawn.

Comment: I don't know man - the only reason I believed the theorem was true was because it was given in a standard book (S L Loney) and has been copied from there onto other texts too. As I have a doubt in the proof myself, I can't definitely say whether it's true or not? Either way, if it's wrong, could you correct it?

Comment: Standard books can occasionally contain errors. That's why argument from authority is a logical fallacy.

Comment: Comparing to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/610119/409), the region is indeed bounded by the evolute. By that answer, the number of normals is $2$, $3$, or $4$, depending upon a point's relationship to that evolute.

Comment: @Blue: Yes that's the complete answer to the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Here is an example of an interior point _F_ [where four normals to the ellipse exist](https://i.imgur.com/tE4tzAY.png). What you have to show is that since two normals always meet at a point, the locus of those points self-intersects allowing for 2 pairs of 2 points to meet at a single point.

Comment: Nice drawing but wrong conclusion.

Comment: @Moti hm? The theorem is indeed incorrect and the diamond is indeed the evolute, as discussed in the linked duplicate, so I’m not sure what you mean.

Comment: You have drawings that shows two cases - one for a point inside and one of a point outside the ellipse that allow 4 normal to the ellipse - isn't this the claim of the theorem? It does not state that for every ellipse you can get it - for example in the circle case there is only one point that has 4 but the center has infinity.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of such 4 normal:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is two normals and two tangents.

Comment: Those are 4 normal - 2 normal to the tangents drawn and one which is actually two merged. Slight move left or right will split the two through the center of the ellipse into two. Total 4.

Comment: This is what [four normals through a single point _F_ look like](https://i.imgur.com/tE4tzAY.png).

Comment: This is the case when the point is in the ellipse. There is a range for such points in and out of the ellipse/circle.